# WinRT how expensive is reading from local file cache

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml, data-caching

I am building a winrt metro app and always seem to run into this (non?) issue.

I find myself maintaining a lot of files of cached data that I can serialize back and forth. Data retrieved from services, user selected items and so on.

The question that I always seem to have when I write the calls is: is it the accessing of the actual file (and releasing etc)  that takes time/is expensive or the amount of data that needs to be serialized from it?

How much should I worry about, for example, trying to combine a couple of files that may have the same object types stored into one and then identifying the ones I need once I have the objects 'out'.

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever get `insufficient Memory` or `memory out of bounds exception`.

Winrt lets you use the ram and the cached file upto around 70-80% of its memory . Any thing beyond that will crash the app. Once you navigate away fro your page your resorces are garbage collected so thats not an issue. But if you are  using using for the memory stream then also it will be fine but saving large data and continiously fetching files from the data base effects system memory. And since surface tablets have limited memory set so should take a bit care about large number of files :) i faced this while rendering bitmaps as loading around 100 bitmaps simultaneously into the memory threw `insufficient memory exception`.